# Single Sign-On on Winforms Web Browser control

Tags: c#, winforms, single-sign-on

I have a Winforms app which hosts a web browser control. Within this control you can also navigate to pre-determined external websites.

I need to implement Single Sign-On so that the user doesn't need to authenticate in each of the known external websites. I have already some ideas but it would be nice to hear all your opinions.

What would be the best way to do this?

In fact, is there something already for this? (edit: how do browsers remember logins/passwords)?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is the responsibility of the site to implement SSO, and the client will then automatically respond to the site. Since the web browser control is using IE it inherits the same capabilities as the web browser. For example if the site uses [Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) then the control will authenticate following a challenge from the site without user intervention. Similarly the control will perform the necessary redirects if the site is using [SAML 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0).

Since these are external websites I have to assume that Windows Authentication is not going to work well because the server and the client are on different domains. Therefore something along the lines of SAML sounds like the most secure option.

It seems like implementing SAML is going to be a problem for you and you need to manually complete and submit web forms which load inside the control. This is possible by accessing the DOM but it quickly becomes a difficult to maintain solution.

The web browser control offers up a [document property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) that gives you an [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx) object which allows you to [find elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) and [execute JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx) in pages. You need to use these mechanisms to automatically perform the authentication. The steps might look like this:

1. Capture URL, or some cookie that will let you know if authentication is required by inspecting the web browser control properties. You might want to look into [OnNavigate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.onnavigated.aspx).
2. Access the document and complete the form values.
3. Call a JavaScript submit function to submit the form, or inject some JavaScript to do this. I find it easier to insert JavaScript into pages than to write more complicated C# code in a lot of cases. It is easier to prototype in a regular browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the websites all share a common trusted authentication mechanism (like [OpenID](http://openid.net/)) you're stuck doing custom coding for each site.

Browsers remember passwords for single sites. I wouldn't call that "single sign-on", which is a method of using a trusted authority to authenticate across multiple **disparate** web sites which all rely on that authority to verify a user's identity.

As you asked for SSO packages that already do this, some examples are:

- RSA ClearTrust
- [CA SiteMinder](http://www.ca.com/us/internet-access-control.aspx)

Comment: All of the websites don't share a common trusted authentication mechanism (well, if they did most likely I wouldn't have to do anything anyway). I have no control of them as they are external systems. The thing that I would like to do is something like how browsers recognize forms for a particular website and pre-fill in with the user's data, after that I would just have to submit the form for the user (just one of my ideas). Do you know some API or something to do this? That's my goal...